# Why am I receiving erratic CPU performance counter values in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, performance

I've read multiple SO posts about the proper way to use the CPU performance counter; and that the first result will always return 0. The problem is the 2nd value that is returned is completely inaccurate, regardless of the time between the two calls. We have a computer with 8 total processor cores, which idles around 1-2% CPU. Here is a sample of return values once a second:

```
12.25, 3.47, 0, 23.95, 12.25, 27.85, 6.4, 0, 16.15, 53.2
```

I watched the total CPU the entire time in Task Manager, and it never went over 5%.

```
CPU = GetCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total")

Private Function GetCounter(category As String, counter As String, Optional instance As String = Nothing) As Double
    Using pc As New PerformanceCounter(category, counter, instance)
        pc.NextValue()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Return pc.NextValue()
    End Using
End Function
```

Changing the sleep time to 500ms / 1000ms does not help either. Why the erratic values?

Answer (score 0):

The CPU usage performance counter is kind of odd. If you look in task manager you will see this unexpected process called "System Idle Process".

[image]

What does "System Idle Process" do? Why is it always using up my CPU time? Well, the fact is, the CPU is always running at full speed, even if there is no work for it to do. If there is nothing to do, then the "System Idle Process" is the one that is running.

So, what does the CPU usage performance counter measure? Simply, it measures 100% - (System Idle Process%). That is to say, 100 minus whatever the "System Idle Process" uses. BUT, you can't exactly measure CPU usage for a given process. It always has to be over some period of time. Say you look at it over 1 second. This is pretty normal for when you are looking in Task Manager:

[image]

But you can turn this update speed up or down. So what if you could turn the update speed way up? What would you see? What if the "System Idle Process" % was the average for 10 ms? 1ms? You would obviously see a lot more spikes. In 1ms, you could easily see a spike to 50 or 100% on a machine that appeared to be idling. This is probably what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, I increased the interval on task manager, and the two readings are just so crazily different I don't think it's an update speed problem.